# trying to redirect input and output using system calls

Tags: c, system-calls

i'm trying to read an input from a specific file and write it to a specific file using unix(sys calls). the output part must be somehow created.

i want to do something like the following:
./a.out < input.txt > output.txt
using only these functions: fork,dup.dup2,exec,open,write,read
the code is this :

```
pid_t   pid, runner;
char *path = argv[1];
char enter[] = "/home/demo/Desktop/OS/Ex1/Ex12/code/input.txt";
char to[] = "/home/demo/Desktop/OS/Ex1/Ex12/Ex1/ronen/";
char *out = "/home/demo/Desktop/OS/Ex1/Ex12/Ex1/ronen/out1.txt";
char *args[] = {to, "./a.out","<",enter,">",out, NULL};
char *args2[] = {"cd", to, "./a.out","<",enter,">",to ,NULL};
if ((runner = fork()) < 0) {perror("could not make fork");}
else if (runner == 0) {
    printf("true\n");
    execvp(args2[0],args2);
} else if (runner != 0) {
    waitpid(runner,0,0);
    printf("done\n");
}
```

So it's actaully working when i put the "a.out" file in the desktop.

however has anyone know how i can redirect the exec function to go to my spefic folder? so i won't have to pass the executable file to the desktop?

Comment: You don't get the concepts of `shell` and `syscall`. You should first try to better understand what are syscalls and what does the shell before writing code. For instance you're trying to pass a shell command line to the kernel. This is nonsense, the shell **is** responsible for translating the command line into the correct arguments to the fork/exec sequence.

Comment: Is your question: *How to write a program which launch a second program whose standard input and output are redirected to files ?*

Answer (score 0):

For reading and writing files, you just use the normal `read` and `write` functions; you'll need to have a file descriptor first, so you'll need to use `fopen`.

all in all, every C tutorial I've ever seen covers opening and writing long before it touches `fork`, so I wonder what you've been following. I'd really just recommend finding an intro to C that you like and read the first few pages; if you already understand what `fork` does, this will be a piece of cake for you.

**EDIT**: also, you might misunderstand what

```
program arguments <from_file >to_file
```

does when using that on a shell:

The **shell** reads that line, and calls `program`, passing it `arguments` as... arguments. It detects the `<` and `>` on that line and "bends" the standard input and output file descriptors (yes, standard input and output behave just like that), to be actually `fopen`ed files.

`program` never sees `<from_file` nor `>to_file`.

**EDIT** in your comment you say:

> i can not use fopen and those functions. only .fork,dup.dup2,exec,open,write,read

Obviously, `fopen` is but a wrapper for `open` and returns the file descriptor `open` returns.

Also, your program uses plenty libc functions; if you'd only be allowed to `write`, you shouldn't use `printf`, which is a very handy formatting wrapper for `puts`, which is a wrapper for `write`. Similar things apply to **all** functions you call, ie. `waitpid`, `execvp`, `perror`. You should document your requirements clearly *for yourself*, first.

Comment: Hi first of all thanks for comenting!
but i can not use fopen and those functions. only  .fork,dup.dup2,exec,open,write,read

Comment: i don't understand how to make a command "./a.out <input.txt>output.txt"
using the sys call dup

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is: *How to write a program which launch a second program whose standard input and output are redirected to files ?*

In that case you need to follow this sequence:

**In the main program**

- fork() a child process
- wait() for the child process using the pid obtained from fork()

**In the child subprocess**

- close(0) the standard input
- open() the input file (with read mode)
- close(1) the standard output
- open() the output file (with write mode)
- exec() the target program

**How to use syscalls**

**R**ead **T**he **F**ine **M**anuals

- [close](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/close.html)
- [dup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dup.html)
- [exec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html)
- [fork](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html)
- [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html)

All these man page contains *example code*. And by reading all of them you should have enough example code to write your whole program.

Comment: my question is regarding the exec command which i don't understand.
for instance, say i would like to use "a.out" coomand and only that command. what are the arguments i must pass the execvp function.
Thank you.